# VirtualBox Dynamic Disk not growing to max size

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-disk

I have a VMDK format drive. Actual size is 5MB, virtual is 40GB. The guest is tiny core linux (it's from [boot2docker](https://github.com/steeve/boot2docker)), created using `VBoxManage createhd --format VMDK --filename boot2docker.vmdk --size 40000`

fdisk cannot read the partitions, so I don't know if the issue is an undersized partition (perhaps I need to install a driver)

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 41.9 GB, 41943040000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 5099 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Disk /dev/sda doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Any advice on either viewing the partition table or helping me to use the full disk space would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you didn't read: `40gb HDD (not initialized, see FAQ)`

And at the bottom of the page (the FAQ)

> **Hard Disk Persistence using Virtualbox**
>
> ```
> sudo -s
> fdisk /dev/sda
> n    # new primary partition
> p
> 1   # first partition
> Enter  # default start
> Enter  # default end
> w  # write partition table and quit
> mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
> reboot
> ```

Comment: Oh...wow. Embarrassing, but thanks for helping me see it!